# Is it common for repair of Reaper keyspace to generate lots of log messages?

Tags: cassandra

Im new to stackoverflow , I have one q-

We have apache cassandra 4 , with 10+10 nodes in 2 DC's.

Our logs(systems logs)  are directly pushed to Kibana , for logs search (not keeping the logs on the node).

Whenever we run repair on "reaper" keyspace , ( 9 tables) , generating lots of INFO messages(around 100,000) messages and getting alert from Kibana , saying threshold exceeded.

Is it common to generate lots of info messages during repair (especially reaper KS).

thanks in advance

Akku.

running KS repair - reaper from reaper tool.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "common" but the quick answer is yes, Cassandra will log whatever messages are necessary as part of the repair. Cheers!

Comment: okay thanks Erick, for the response ,can we disable info message generation on cassandra , I can see multiple logging options ,https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/configuration/configLoggingLevels.html. ; can we disable only info logging ?

Comment: That's a different question to what you originally asked so please post it on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. If we keep responding to new questions in the comments, it will be a never-ending thread. Cheers!